# Why Java is not launching when I use version 7 instead of 6?

Tags: java, version, java-7, java-6, launching-application

When I install version 7 of Java on my windows 7 64 bit machine (I install this version [64 bit, windows with SDK](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b05/jdk-7u3-windows-x64.exe)) then Java does not launch when entering a website with applet. But when I use version 6 everything works fine.

On the other hand, while compiling (with Netbeans 7.1.1) everything works fine on both of these versions. Java programs also work fine when launched from command line with `java` command.

What is going on?

**EDIT**

Now I have tried reinstalling everything with Java 7 update 4 (64bits) but it still does not work. The problem might be somewhere in `PATH` variable because the java icon does not appear in the tray when I am entering a site with applet but still - I have added `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` to `PATH` and it does not work.

Comment: did you install the JRE?

Comment: @aglassman I use Opera but I have also tried it in Firefox.

Comment: You may have to install a java plugin for the browser.

Comment: Do you see the Java plugin listed if you enter "about:plugins" in Opera's address bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Plugin must be in same hardware specification than the browser.

So if you install Java 64bits, it will run in IE 8 or 9 64bits.

But Firefox is only provided as 32 bits binary for Windows from the standard download channel. You should try with [Firefox 64 bits](http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Download).

Probably your Opera version is 32 bits too...

I invite you to cross-check by installing a 32 bits browser (Firefox standard binaries) and a JDK 32 bits on Windows 7 64 bits. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that your Java path environmental variables weren't updated.  Check out this [link](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml). Make sure its pointing java to the 7 exe.

Comment: I have added this directory to `PATH` : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` but still nothing happens

Comment: Did you remove the Java 6 Path value? Also I would restart your PC.

Comment: I still have these 2 environment variables `QTJAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip` and `CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip`. But there is no equivalent to this QTJava.zip in version 7 folder.

Comment: QTJava is the Quicktime player.  This shouldn't interfere with running a Java applet.  Do a restart and try the applet again.

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox, IE, Chrome?

Comment: I use Firefox for that (compatibility issues with Opera).

Comment: In the Tools->Add-on page, what java is listed?

Comment: As far as I know, Chrome doesn't actually list Java in its extensions page.

Comment: @Patryk is using Firefox not Chrome.

Comment: @eabraham I think this might be the problem cuz I have in Add-on Page `Java Deployment Toolkit 6.0.310.5` installed. How can I change that ?

Comment: @eabraham It says that it is up to date. I have now reinstalled all : JDK + eclipse. (JDK version 1.6u31) and now even this one does not work. I am confused.